# Trying to figure out how to use socket.io the correct way in a useEffect that is using an axios get request to fetch messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

So far i'm stuck on my useEffect that fetches all the current messages and renders the state accordingly. as of right now it doesn't render the new state until page is refreshed.

```js
const Home = ({ user, logout }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const [activeConversation, setActiveConversation] = useState(null);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const addSearchedUsers = (users) => {
    const currentUsers = {};

    // make table of current users so we can lookup faster
    conversations.forEach((convo) => {
      currentUsers[convo.otherUser.id] = true;
    });

    const newState = [...conversations];
    users.forEach((user) => {
      // only create a fake convo if we don't already have a convo with this user
      if (!currentUsers[user.id]) {
        let fakeConvo = { otherUser: user, messages: [] };
        newState.push(fakeConvo);
      }
    });

    setConversations(newState);
  };

  const clearSearchedUsers = () => {
    setConversations((prev) => prev.filter((convo) => convo.id));
  };

  const saveMessage = async (body) => {
    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/messages", body);
    return data;
  };

  const sendMessage = (data, body) => {
    socket.emit("new-message", {
      message: data.message,
      recipientId: body.recipientId,
      sender: data.sender,
    });
  };

  const postMessage = async (body) => {
    try {
      const data = await saveMessage(body);

      if (!body.conversationId) {
        addNewConvo(body.recipientId, data.message);
      } else {
        addMessageToConversation(data);
      }
      sendMessage(data, body);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  const addNewConvo = useCallback(
    (recipientId, message) => {
      conversations.forEach((convo) => {
        if (convo.otherUser.id === recipientId) {
          convo.messages.push(message);
          convo.latestMessageText = message.text;
          convo.id = message.conversationId;
        }
      });
      setConversations(conversations);
    },
    [setConversations, conversations],
  );

  const addMessageToConversation = useCallback(
    (data) => {
      // if sender isn't null, that means the message needs to be put in a brand new convo
      const { message, sender = null } = data;
      if (sender !== null) {
        const newConvo = {
          id: message.conversationId,
          otherUser: sender,
          messages: [message],
        };
        newConvo.latestMessageText = message.text;
        setConversations((prev) => [newConvo, ...prev]);
      }
      conversations.forEach((convo) => {
        console.log('hi', message.conversationId)
        if (convo.id === message.conversationId) {
          const convoCopy = { ...convo }
          convoCopy.messages.push(message);
          convoCopy.latestMessageText = message.text;
          console.log('convo', convoCopy)

        } else {
          return convo
        }
      });
      setConversations(conversations);
    },
    [setConversations, conversations],
  );

  const setActiveChat = useCallback((username) => {
    setActiveConversation(username);
  }, []);

  const addOnlineUser = useCallback((id) => {
    setConversations((prev) =>
      prev.map((convo) => {
        if (convo.otherUser.id === id) {
          const convoCopy = { ...convo };
          convoCopy.otherUser = { ...convoCopy.otherUser, online: true };
          return convoCopy;
        } else {
          return convo;
        }
      }),
    );
  }, []);

  const removeOfflineUser = useCallback((id) => {
    setConversations((prev) =>
      prev.map((convo) => {
        if (convo.otherUser.id === id) {
          const convoCopy = { ...convo };
          convoCopy.otherUser = { ...convoCopy.otherUser, online: false };
          return convoCopy;
        } else {
          return convo;
        }
      }),
    );
  }, []);

  // Lifecycle

  useEffect(() => {
    // Socket init
    socket.on("add-online-user", addOnlineUser);
    socket.on("remove-offline-user", removeOfflineUser);
    socket.on("new-message", addMessageToConversation);

    return () => {
      // before the component is destroyed
      // unbind all event handlers used in this component
      socket.off("add-online-user", addOnlineUser);
      socket.off("remove-offline-user", removeOfflineUser);
      socket.off("new-message", addMessageToConversation);
    };
  }, [addMessageToConversation, addOnlineUser, removeOfflineUser, socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // when fetching, prevent redirect
    if (user?.isFetching) return;

    if (user && user.id) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      // If we were previously logged in, redirect to login instead of register
      if (isLoggedIn) history.push("/login");
      else history.push("/register");
    }
  }, [user, history, isLoggedIn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchConversations = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/conversations");
        setConversations(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    if (!user.isFetching) {
      fetchConversations();
    }
  }, [user]);

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    if (user && user.id) {
      await logout(user.id);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</Button>
      <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <SidebarContainer
          conversations={conversations}
          user={user}
          clearSearchedUsers={clearSearchedUsers}
          addSearchedUsers={addSearchedUsers}
          setActiveChat={setActiveChat}
        />
        <ActiveChat
          activeConversation={activeConversation}
          conversations={conversations}
          user={user}
          postMessage={postMessage}
        />
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```

this is the main part im working on, the project had starter code when i began and was told not to touch the backend so i know its something wrong with the front end code.  i feel like im missing something important for the socket.io

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

import React from 'react';


export const socket = io(window.location.origin);
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to server');
});

export const SocketContext = React.createContext();
```

this is how i have the socket.io setup, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be cool. I have been reading up on socket.io as much as I can but am still pretty lost on it.

Comment: Why do you think its a problem with the frontend sockets?

Comment: Thank you i'll give it a try, its just because my teacher gave us the starting code and the backend had already been completed and its passing all of its tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption the backend is working properly...

```
  const addNewConvo = useCallback(
    (recipientId, message) => {
      conversations.forEach((convo) => {
        if (convo.otherUser.id === recipientId) {
          convo.messages.push(message);
          convo.latestMessageText = message.text;
          convo.id = message.conversationId;
        }
      });
      setConversations(conversations);
    },
    [setConversations, conversations],
  );
```

`setConversations(conversations);`

This is an incorrect way to set a state using the state's variable, and such it wont do anything. Likely why your code wont change until refresh.

Suggested fix:

```
  const addNewConvo = useCallback(
    (recipientId, message) => {
        setConversations(previousState => previousState.map(convo => {
        if (convo.otherUser.id === recipientId) {
            convo.messages.push(message)
            convo.latestMessageText = message.text;
            convo.id = message.conversationId;
            return convo
        }
        return convo
      }))
    },
    [setConversations, conversations],
  );
```

note: even above could be done more efficiently since I made a deep copy of messages

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to resolve it but that is cleaner way to write it for sure. I really need to start practicing writing more efficient code.